# Color coded background on calculated column using Designer

Tags: list, css, calculated-column

I am aware of the various methods to colorcode columns (jquery, formula) I choose here to use designer on allitems.aspx on a list (im lazy and its easy).

I have given various columns background colors based on their values using xsl styles e.g. date > xx etc...works fine.

However... now i notice i have 1 calculated column in there (which display different numbers based on two others columns) where the xsl does not show the background color.

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Level. &lt; 4" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">background-color: #33CC33;</xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Level. &gt; 4 and $thisNode/@Level. &lt; 9" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">background-color: #FFFF00;</xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Level. &gt; 9 and $thisNode/@Level. &lt; 17" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">background-color: #FF9900;</xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Level. &gt; 16" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">background-color: #FF0000; color: #FFFFFF;</xsl:if>

</xsl:attribute>
```

When I try to Google for this I find all the hits on "using a calculated column to display colorcoded fields" but I cant find "using designer XSL to colorcode background on a calculated column".

Should I add something extra in there, sort of delayed processing or should I add a jquery clause specifically for this column?

Comment: Isn't it ironic that you use this method because it's easy, but can't get it to work?

Comment: @Christophe : got it to work, answered it. Forgot it was txt.

Answer (score 1):

The field is text so... need to convert it back to numeric e.g.:

```
xsl:if test="number($thisNode/@Level) &lt; '12'"
```

etc... works great.